# Any in-browser way to run queries for MongoDB like pgweb does for postgres/heroku?

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, browser, mongodb-query

So I just starting learning MongoDB and was looking for a similar way to practice it like I do with Postgres. I use Heroku to store my postgres database then connect to pgweb( https://pgweb-demo.herokuapp.com/ ) in there I can view all my data and run queries in browser. I looked, but all the ones I saw for MongoDB required downloading. Was wondering if anybody knew of something similar to pgweb for MongoDB?

Comment: please only use the tags that fit most to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to generate test data and do some find or aggregate or update practice, [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/) might be a good choice.

Otherwise, those tool which required downloading like Robo 3T or MongoDBCompass are your best choice.

Those web gui connect to real database have to sign up first. [acho](https://acho.io/) 、 [humongous](https://www.humongous.io/)